# Is it possible to have a client certificate authentication only for a subdirectory in Tomcat behind Apache?

Tags: apache, authentication, tomcat, client-certificates, subdirectory

Let's say I have

example.com

and I would like a client certificate authentication on

example.com/admin

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps by configuring your (Apache or Lighttpd) web server to act as an HTTP[S] proxy (to another HTTPS server doing the certificate (but I am not sure).